# Pandas replacing a value in dataframe with conditions on string

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I need a bit of help:

I have two columns: id and class:

df:

```
id      class
AB001   NaN
AB002   NaN
CDE001  NaN
CDE002  NaN
```

and what I'd like is that if id begins with AB, then class is AB,

but if

id begins with CDE, then class is CDE

so I'll end up with:

```
id      class
AB001   AB  
AB002   AB
CDE001  CDE
CDE002  CDE
```

I just can't get my head around it - can someone help? Thank you!

Comment: `df['class'] = df['id'].str.replace('\d', '')`

Comment: The number seems to be always 3 digits, so you could slice the string: `df["class"] = df["id"].str[0:-3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to clip all the trailing digits, so:

```
df['class'] = df['id'].str.extract('^(\D+)')[0]
```

Output:

```
       id class
0   AB001    AB
1   AB002    AB
2  CDE001   CDE
3  CDE002   CDE
```

---

**update**: per your comment, you can use `rstrip`:

```
df['class'] = df['id'].str.rstrip('0123456789')
```

or still with `extract`:

```
df['class'] = df['id'].str.extract('^(.*\D)\d+$')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! One final thing - what if I want to specify the number of characters from the left to keep? So for example, I have id = 30DE001, and I want to keep '30DE' in class.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using regex extract

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":['AB001', 'AB002', 'CDE001', 'CDE002']})
df['Class'] = df['id'].str.extract(r"^([A-Z]+)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       id Class
0   AB001    AB
1   AB002    AB
2  CDE001   CDE
3  CDE002   CDE
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for the answer too